# Spark Java | Error reading CSV to typed Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, encoder

I am trying to read `Student` records from a CSV using Spark(Java), and facing errors converting it to a typed `Dataset<Student>`.

**Reader code** :

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("testingSQL").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
Encoder<Student> studentEncoder = Encoders.bean(Student.class);
Dataset<Student> df = spark.read().option("header", true)
                //.schema(studentEncoder.schema())
                .csv("src/main/resources/exams/students2.csv")
                .as(studentEncoder);
df.show();
```

**Student Class**

```java
public class Student implements Serializable {
    int studentId;
    int examCenterId;
    String subject;
    int year;
    int quarter;
    int score;
    String grade;
    // getters and setters
}
```

**CSV file**

```
studentId,examCenterId,subject,year,quarter,score,grade
1,1,Math,2005,1,41,D
1,1,Spanish,2005,1,51,C
1,1,German,2005,1,39,D
1,1,Physics,2005,1,35,D
```

However I am facing the following two problems while trying to read these records :

**Problem 1 :** When the `.schema(studentEncoder.schema())` part is commented out in the reader code, the execution throws an `upcastFailureError`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot up cast score from string to int.
The type path of the target object is:
- field (class: "int", name: "score")
- root class: "com.virtualpairprogrammers.model.Student"
You can either add an explicit cast to the input data or choose a higher precision type of the field in the target object
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryCompilationErrors$.upCastFailureError(QueryCompilationErrors.scala:154)
```

**Problem 2 :** When the `.schema(studentEncoder.schema())` line is uncommented, spark does show the Student rows but the values are shown against incorrect columns, and some columns are null altogether. For ex: score is being shown in the subject column.

| examCenterId | grade | quarter | score | studentId | subject | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null | 2005 | 1 | 41 | null |
| 1 | 1 | null | 2005 | 1 | 51 | null |
| 1 | 1 | null | 2005 | 1 | 39 | null |
| 1 | 1 | null | 2005 | 1 | 35 | null |

What am I missing while setting the encoders or the schema ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to Problem 1** : adding an option to infer the schema solved it.

```java
Dataset<Student> df = spark.read().option("header", true)
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .csv("src/main/resources/exams/students2.csv")
                .as(studentEncoder);
```

**Caveat** : `inferSchema` requires an extra pass over the data.